# Prolog counting elements in list

Tags: list, prolog

I want to count how many g items appear in a list, below is the code I was trying now, but I got false when return.

```
g(E) :- memberchk(E, [apple, orange, pear, grape, lycee, pineapple,dragonfruit]).

countFruit([], No):- write(' >> No of Fruits : '), write(No), nl.
countFruit([H|T], No) :- not(g(H)), countFruit(T,No).
countFruit([H|T], No) :- No1 is No+1, countFruit(T,No1).

?countFruit(H,0). (H is a list).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `?- countFruit(H,0).` you are telling prolog to unify the `No` variable in your `countfruit\2` predicate to `0`. So the result can only ever be `0` or `fail`.

If I run your code as-is though, I get the following:

```
>>NoofFruits:0
Yes.
```

Here's my take on this problem:

```
countFruit(Xs, No) :-
    countFruit(Xs, No, 0).

countFruit([], No, No).
countFruit([H|T], No, X0) :-
    member(H, [apple, orange, pear, grape, lycee, pineapple, dragonfruit]),
    !,
    X1 is X0 + 1,
    countFruit(T, No, X1).
countFruit([_|T], No, X) :-
    countFruit(T, No, X).

?- countFruit([orange, dog, dragonfruit, lycee], X),
    write(" >> No of Fruits : "),
    write(X),
    nl,
    fail.
```

Comment: @user236501 - What do you want to chat about?

Comment: Clarify the printing elements issues

Comment: No worries. It'd be good if you added a link to your new post to the comments here.

Comment: The statement "you are telling prolog to unify the No variable [...] to 0. So the result can only ever be 0 or fail." is wrong. The No variable in the original code functions only as input, so there's no problem with binding it to 0. That the OP got no solution must have had a different reason. Hence my question for the OP's query that resulted in 'false'. Your code is better, nonetheless, although you should use memberchk/2 instead of member/2, in order to avoid problems when calling countFruit/2 with an uninstantiated list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains one bug: since the second and third clause of countFruit/2 use the same head, you should add a cut after the not(g(H)) test in the second clause. Otherwise, you'll get a wrong answer on backtracking.

Also, instead of using not(g(H)), you could simplify the code by checking for g(H) instead and reformulating the second and third clause accordingly. But that's just beautifying.

Other than that, I can't see an obvious problem with your code. Can you supply the actual query that resulted in 'false'?.